# C++ copying and resizing an allocated array initialized using the new operator

Tags: c++, new-operator, arrays

```
int* array1 = new[ 10 ]( );
```

What is the correct way to copy this array? The following is my attempt.

```
int* array2 = array1;
```

With that said, is the following the correct way to add a value to a full array1?

```
int val = 2;
int* array2 = new[ 11 ]( );

for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    array2[ i ] = array1[ i ];
}

array2[ 10 ] = val;
delete [ ]array1;
```

One more question, how do I get the amount of spaces that are filled in an array?

```
int* array1 = new[ 2 ];
array1[ 0 ] = 1;
// the resulting array would look like this { 1 };
```

I want to get the number of initialized elements, so instead of returning 2 for the number of elements the allocated array can hold, I want to get how many elements actually have a value. I want to do this so I can replace the 10 in my previous code with the size of array1.

Thank you!

EDIT: I need to stick with c style arrays because of my instructor.

Comment: Why `new[ 10 ]( )` instead of `new int[10]` ? ...

Comment: It will just fill the array with zeros.

Comment: `new[ 10 ]( )` is a syntax error. Does not even run. `new int[10]` is correct. Declares an array of int whose size is 10. (Not necessarily 0)

Comment: @op it should be `new int[10]()`.

Comment: @cj1094 Thats not right, 1) it doesnt make any difference 2) the values will be random

Comment: you have to learn the difference between values and pointers.

Comment: @Paranaix it does make a difference, it's just not the right syntax. The `()` at the end does value initialization.

Comment: @LoganMurphy see comment above. Also, note that values/pointers have nothing to do with heap/stack. You can have pointers to stack memory just fine. Allocation and lifetime have nothing to do with how you address that memory. Also note that stack/heap are implementation details. The proper C++ nomenclature would be automatic storage, dynamic storage **and** static storage.

Comment: @Paranaix well the values are not random. They are whatever they were when you allocated the memory.

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not just using a std::vector?

Comment: @Logan: No, reading an uninitialized value causes undefined behavior.  You could read the same element 3 times, and they could all be different, if you haven't initialized it yet.

Comment: @cj1094 Your instructor is leading you astray. If you're learning c, this would be applicable. However, if you use this style of coding in c++11, it will only hurt you. C++ has grown from what it used to be. Embracing the new paradigms is essential. Please ask your instructor if he's read the 4th edition of the c++ programming language.

Answer (score 2):

```
int* array2 = array1;
```

assigns one pointer to another, i.e. it copies an address stored in `array1` and makes `array2` to point to this address as well.

If you want to make a deep copy while still using pointers you could use `memcpy`:

```
int* array2 = new int[10];
memcpy(array2, array1, 10 * sizeof(int));
```

which is ghastly C-style approach that you should avoid always when it is possible.

---

The only reasonable solution that I can think of is using `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of
C-style arrays. `std::vector` unlike an array is an object that has its own assignment operator (as well as copy constructor) that copies it for you the way you would expect it:

```
std::vector<int> vec1(10, 0);  // 10 numbers initialized to 0
std::vector<int> vec2 = vec1;  // note this actually calls copy constructor
std::vector<int> vec3(vec1);   // the same as previous line
vec3 = vec1;                   // assignment that makes a deep copy for you
```

You can start with an empty `std::vector` and keep pushing new elements to it using its `push_back` method and retrieve its size at any time calling `vec.size()`. Additionally: you are not responsible for cleaning up the memory where its elements were stored - if you use it as I pointed out in the above code, these are objects with automatic storage duration that clean up the memory for you when they go out of scope.

Comment: Further: vector keeps track of its size (actually used elements), and can be resized.  Pretty much everything the OP is trying to do, vector already does.

Comment: +1 std::vector should be preferred in this case. Please read http://www.amazon.com/The-Programming-Language-4th-Edition/dp/0321563840 for a more complete rationale outlining the c+11 standard library and RAII.

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt doesn't copy the contents of the array, it simply creates a new pointer that points to the beginning of the array.

Your method of adding a value looks correct.

The array itself does not remember which members you have assigned values to. If you want to keep track of how many elements are "filled", you'll have to do that yourself. You could wrap the array in, say, a template class, and perhaps call it `myVector`.